# how to eliminate a value null in Json encode Yii2?

Tags: php, jquery, json, yii2

I am trying to create or update a model in modal and the answer will be null after Json and my modal is not hidden after the action. network show this

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 103 of the JSON data

AFTER `{"status":true,"type":"success","title":"¡Excelente!","msj":"Se han guardado los datos correctamente"}null`, this null of the end, Whats mean? 
[image]

My actions looks like:

```
public function run($id = null)
{
    if ($id == null) {
        $model = new BancosConcepto();
    } else {
        $model = BancosConcepto::findOne($id);
    }

    $model->loadDefaultValues();
    $show_form = true;

    $data = array();
    if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
        $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());

        if($model->save()) {
            $show_form = false;
            $data['status'] = true;
            $data['type'] = 'success';
            $data['title'] = '¡Excelente!';
            $data['message'] = 'El concepto se registró correctamente.';
        }
    }

    if ($show_form) {
        return $this->controller->renderAjax('_form', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    } else {
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        echo JSON::encode($data);
    }
}
```

My view looks like:

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".btn-add", function(e) {

    url = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        beforeSend: function() {    
            $("#modal-win .modal-dialog").addClass("modal-sm")
            $("#modal-win").modal('show');
        },
        success: function(data){
            $("#modal-win .modal-content").html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;

});
```

Comment: This is not in your JSON `{...json...}null` its something output after it.  Do `exit(JSON::encode($data));`  And check `ob_get_level()`  to make sure there is no output buffers on, it should be 0  After you send your JSON response it should be the end of the application as you can send only one Json response.  You could have `?>null` in one of your files etc.  Who knows.  PS I don't use Yii.

Comment: add exit() after "echo JSON::encode($data);"

Comment: I didn't have any null, I create a new proyect and add this views and network says same. 
Could install Json version for this?

Comment: I have an other proyect with yii version 2.0.11 and works great, the new proyect have a version 2.0.14 and generate this problem, any answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your action should return response instead of echo it:

```
if ($show_form) {
    return $this->controller->renderAjax('_form', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
} else {
    return $this->controller->asJson($data);
}
```